# Dropwizard and Jersey SSE (Server side events)

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard, server-sent-events

Does anyone used this [Jersey SSE feature](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html) already in a Dropwizard application? I tried it with DW 0.9.1 but all I get is this Exception at startup:

```
[main]: /:?:?- unavailable
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventOutput .......
```

Authentication and Authorization is also done like [here](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.1/docs/manual/auth.html) with SecurityContext. I tried also a very simple no authentication/authorization app and there is the same problem. Perhaps I have to register SSE, but I dont know how if this solves my problem, because Jersey documentation says that there is a automated registering since version 2.8.x.

What i tried, but does not help:

```
    environment.jersey().register(SseFeature.class);
    environment.jersey().getResourceConfig().register(SseFeature.class);
    System.out.println("sse feature:" + environment.jersey().getResourceConfig().getConfiguration().isRegistered(SseFeature.class));
```

Output:

```
...
sse feature:true
WARN  [2015-11-11 10:12:58,845] [main]: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors:?:?- The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Cannot create new registration for component type class org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.SseFeature: Existing previous registration found for the type.
...
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem or have any ideas?

Comment: Now It works. I have done this: environment.jersey().register(new EventOutputMesssageBodyWriter());

The MsgBodyWriter does no write, but it works.

Comment: Please provide this comment as an answer and mark it, so this thread can be considered closed. This way the solution will be available efficiently for others to use too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really strange problem. Dont know why it works now. Perhaps if others have the same problem, I have done this:

```
environment.jersey().register(new EventOutputMesssageBodyWriter());
```

The MsgBodyWriter does no write (writeTo method is empty), but it works. Really strange ...